# pusleaudio pactl: set-source-volume vs set-source-output-volume?

Tags: pulseaudio

what's the difference between set-source-volume and set-source-output-volume?
source means microphone. then what is output volume again?

man page doesn't help actually...

```
 set-source-volume SOURCE VOLUME [VOLUME ...]
              Set  the  volume  of  the  specified  source  (identified  by  its symbolic name or
              numerical index). VOLUME can be specified as  an  integer  (e.g.  2000,  16384),  a
              linear  factor  (e.g. 0.4, 1.100), a percentage (e.g. 10%, 100%) or a decibel value
              (e.g. 0dB, 20dB). If the volume specification start  with  a  +  or  -  the  volume
              adjustment  will  be  relative  to the current source volume. A single volume value
              affects all channels; if multiple volume values are given their number has to match
              the source's number of channels.

set-source-output-volume OUTPUT VOLUME [VOLUME ...]
          Set  the volume of the specified source output (identified by its numerical index).
          VOLUME can be specified as an integer (e.g. 2000, 16384),  a  linear  factor  (e.g.
          0.4,  1.100), a percentage (e.g. 10%, 100%) or a decibel value (e.g. 0dB, 20dB). If
          the volume specification start with a + or - the volume adjustment will be relative
          to the current source output volume. A single volume value affects all channels; if
          multiple volume values are given their number has  to  match  the  source  output's
          number of channels.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what's the difference between using `pactl`and `pacmd` but I use the later for this, and it has a `list-source-outputs` command.

You can use the indexes returned by `pacmd list-source-outputs` to configure output volume per source output.

For example right now I have a loobpack module mixing my phone's music from mic/line-in input with computer sounds and have them over the speakers, which I singled out below:

```
    index: 291
    driver: <module-loopback.c>
    flags: START_CORKED 
    state: RUNNING
    source: 213 <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo>
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    requested latency: 66.67 ms
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    resample method: (null)
    owner module: 204
    properties:
        media.role = "abstract"
        module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-media-role:abstract"
        media.name = "Loopback to Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        media.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

I can set the volume at 50% with this command:

```
pacmd set-source-output-volume 291 32768
```

I could of course do the same from the input, although I'd have less granularity. To use it as a line-in input I set the volume down to the base volume which is just 10% (6554). This input doubles down as a microphone input so the preamp has to be turned down.

Setting the source sink volume could also be used to get different volume levels on multiple sinks from a single same input. You could for ex. record multiple master channels at 100% while mixing them on a monitor at different levels.